# Restoring raw wordpress backup

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on LAMP server in ubuntu. The problem I am facing is, I have a backed up project(.zip format) which was taken from another wordpress instance using.
I have tried different plugins to restore it, but the plugin wants the data to be backed up and restore by the same plugin. I dont know what plugin was used to back up the data
Zip File Structure :

-wp-admin/
-wp-content/
-wp-includes/
-Files

I am not able to restore this back up on my installed wordpress in my local system (mentioned above). Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?